# Unable to retrieve value sent from controller to view in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I am writing a simple maven web project to display a hello world on view when it is invoked. In addition to this I am using apache tomcat 7.
I am following [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm) 

The Controller is getting invoked and I am able to set and print the modelmap.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>springmvc</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
</build>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialpoint" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/hello/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

HelloController

```
package com.tutorialpoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    public HelloController(){
        System.out.println("hiii");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method  = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(Model model){

        System.out.println("this is controller");
        model.addAttribute("testvalue", "Hello World!!");
        System.out.println(model.toString());

        return "output";
    }
}
```

Output.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Output</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is output jsp page  message is </p> ${testvalue}
</body>
</html>
```

But on resulting view(output.jsp) I am unable to fetch the value.
I tried

1. using spring core tag in jsp
2. using the c:out tag
3. putting maven dependency for jstl

Thanks in advance.

Edit - adding output.jsp screen shot

[image]

Comment: Can you see output.jsp ?

Comment: You're not able to resolve given model value but does the rest of your view being rendered in your browser?

Comment: hi yes , output.jsp is loading with this generating -->This is output jsp page message is 
${testvalue}

Comment: I dont know its typo but you are returning "output" and your file name is Output.jsp (issue related to Uppercase of 'O') ?

Comment: I have added the output.jsp screen shot.

Comment: Try to evaluate this expression: ${'output'} in your view and tell me if it worked and this string appeared on your screen.

Comment: printing as it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use EL you need to declare your deployment descriptor (web.xml) as Servlet 2.4 or higher. As you use Tomcat 7 which supports Servlet 3.0 I'd recommend you to use that version.

You can achieve it by changing your opening bracket in web.xml to this:

```
<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

If that hasn't resolved your problem try to include below directive in your view:

`<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>`

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Here the problem is with the `web.xml` header

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

Change it to the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

You don't need to add `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` to every page instead change the `web.xml` header once.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work, as you are modifying the `modal` in controller and then moving to new `view` altogether which will have its own `model`. Hence any change you do will be `nullified`.

I would recommend you to use `flash attribute` facility of Spring MVC by adding `RedirectAttributes` in your controller method as follows,

```
 @RequestMapping(method  = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(Model model, RedirectAttributes redir){

        System.out.println("this is controller");
       // model.addAttribute("testvalue", "Hello World!!");
        redir.addFlashAttribute("testvalue", "Hello World!!");
        System.out.println(model.toString());

        return "redirect:/output";
    }
```

Or Create a new `ModelAndView` and return it,

```
 @RequestMapping(method  = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView printHello(Model model){

        ModelAndView model= new ModelAndView("output");
        System.out.println("this is controller");
        model.addAttribute("testvalue", "Hello World!!");
        System.out.println(model.toString());

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: As per the spring documentation they are following this practice . check this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html . I tried what ppodraza said and it is working fine